Jenkins Installation Fails with Error 1603 Using Chocolatey on Windows
I'm encountering an issue while installing Jenkins via Chocolatey on Windows. Initially, I received an error about Java not being available, which I resolved by setting JAVA_HOME and updating the Path environment variable to use JDK 11 (more info here). However, I'm now facing a different problem during the installation of Jenkins.
The detailed error message from Chocolatey was:
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Installing the following packages:
jenkins
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading jenkins 2.440.2... 100%

jenkins v2.440.2 [Approved]
jenkins package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Installing jenkins...
WARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\jenkins_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.
ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jenkins\tools\jenkins.msi" /qn /norestart /l*v "C:\Users\FoadS\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\jenkins.2.440.2.MsiInstall.log" JENKINS_ROOT="C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\" ] was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\jenkins_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error..
The install of jenkins was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jenkins\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - jenkins (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\jenkins\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

I have already tried rebooting my system and checking the MSI log file, but I couldn't find any clear indication of what might be wrong.
Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
P.S.1. you may find the jenkins_msi_install.log file resulted from running choco install jenkins -y --install-arguments="/l*v c:\jenkins_msi_install.log" here.
P.S.2. trying this solution, the command net user administrator /active:yes returned:
The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2245.

and the command Net user administrator "<password>" /add as suggested here, returned:
The account already exists.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2224.

I could activate the user by running net user administrator * and then following the prompts to enter a new password. However, after all, it did not solve the problem!

We will need the log to diagnose the problem. Have you tried manually running chocolateyinstall.ps1?

@Ramhound here is the jenkins_msi_install.log file.

What about the other question? Your system requires you set a password for the Administrator user in order to activate it.  You can't add a user named Administrator, since that is the name of the default Administrator account, you can certainly create a different Administrator account called something other than Administrator. Since the relevant information from the log is not contained int he question body, it will take upwards of 24 hours, before I can look at the log.

@Ramhound I merely trying to follow this answer,  admittedly not knowing exactly what it does. Nevertheless, the net user administrator * solved the issue with that solution, though that solution did not work for my case.
